# Viewpager with date as title in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to replicate this screen. I think they use `ViewPager` for these . But I want to know how to set the dates as title for these pages .

[image: Sample]

Comment: Posting some code will help us alot

Comment: you can check this. http://avtar-guleria.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-date-slider-with-view-pager.html